# native DLL acess denied UWP

Tags: c++, dll, uwp

I am trying to develope a UWP application for Windows Iot Core Raspberry Pi that uses a native DLL. 
I have cross compiled the native DLL for ARM and Compilation is all fine.

The problem is that the native DLL tries to Access Removable storage using CreateFile2 and returns Access denied.
I have added the permissions for removable media in manifest and also the file extension for which it is permitted to create.

But still unsuccessful.

Comment: Could you show more detail about the destination path that was accessed?

Comment: @Nico Zhu F:\text.txt is the path. This is the path returned by path method of StorageFolder Class. I am able to create a file using CreateFileAsync method but normal windows create file returns Acess denied.

Comment: Do you want to access SD card?

Comment: I have used `CreateFileAsync` method to create file in the  `Removable storage` and it works fine in my side. Could you show more code and the file extension you written?

Comment: @Nico Zhu CreateFileAsync also works for me. I am acessing SD card with usb reader. I have to pass file path to a native DLL for which I get acess denied. Also CreateFile2 works with the local app folder without a problem but does not work with external storage

Answer (score 0):

> CreateFileAsync also works for me. I am acessing SD card with usb reader. I have to pass file path to a native DLL for which I get acess denied. Also CreateFile2 works with the local app folder without a problem but does not work with external storage

When called from a Windows Store app, CreateFile2 is simplified. You can open only files or directories inside the ApplicationData.LocalFolder or Package.InstalledLocation directories. You can't open named pipes or mailslots or create encrypted files (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED).

For more you could refer to [**CreateFile2 function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422(v=vs.85).aspx) and  [**Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).